# CSS Vertical Center inline element?

Tags: css, html

Hello I can't get an anchor tag vertically centered within unordered list. My CSS is:

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    margin-left: 9.814814814814815%; /* 106 / 1080 */
    margin-right: 10.092592592592593%; /* 109 / 1080 */
    width: 80%; /* 864 / 1080 */
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

nav {
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 5.0595238095238096%; /* 85 / 1680 */
    height:  5.476190476190476%; /* 92 / 1680 */
}
```

Then here's my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/get_involved">get involved</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that shows the problem?

Comment: how about ``margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`` on the ``nav ul li a``?

Comment: @thirtydot [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHGNr/1/)

Comment: Are you set on making your nav height a percentage?  Specifying a fixed height would make it much easier to vertically center menu items.  Also, you are aware that setting the font-size as a percentage will not result in the character height scaling as the viewable area's height changes, as it is a percentage of the parent font size?

Comment: @MarkM Thank you for the first point, I have now set it to a fixed height. Then on point 2 I am aware that setting a `font-size` as a percentage it will not scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve "vertical centering", add either line-height or padding to your `<a>` elements:

```
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

You can also adjust the height of the parent `<li>` element to fine-tune the "centering".

Comment: thx for the answer. @Leonhardt Wille your solution works as well.